# How can I de-duplicate an Avahi address?

Tags: networking, hostname, avahi

My laptop has the Avahi address `laptop-2.local` instead of `laptop.local` (which was the address the last time I used it). There is no other machine on the network with the hostname `laptop`, nor has there been.

How can I force Avahi to call it `laptop.local` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the laptop resolved the problem. Presumably the hostname was conflicting with itself.

(Of course, I'd prefer a solution that didn't involve a reboot.)